# Get order by increment_id thru REST API

Tags: rest-api

I am trying this syntax but it returns no results. I am trying to get a single order based on `increment_id`. I have no issue getting an order thru the `entity_id`.

> /rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=12345

returns

> {"items":[],"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"increment_id","value":null,"condition_type":"eq"}]}]},"total_count":0}

Internal ID 12345 is valid, and you can see it's not passed back as filter result.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this , I have verified it and it's working.

```
https://yourdomain.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2506100006387135&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=2&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC
```

Comment: I just tried this but it's still not working.      searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&amp;searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=7000000002&amp;searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&amp;searchCriteria[pageSize]=2&amp;searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&amp;searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC and the result is {"items":[],"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"increment_id","value":null,"condition_type":"eq"}]}]},"total_count":0}

Comment: It seems there is no record for this increment id.

Comment: have u made any customization

Comment: I went back to verify the order ID, still get the error

Comment: GET /rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=increment_id&amp;searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=6000000008&amp;searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&amp;searchCriteria[pageSize]=2&amp;searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=created_at&amp;searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][direction]=DESC&amp;Authorisation=Bearer&amp;Accept=application/ and response again is {"items":[],"search_criteria":{"filter_groups":[{"filters":[{"field":"increment_id","value":null,"condition_type":"eq"}]}]},"total_count":0}

Comment: also tried GET /rest/V1/orders/?Authorisation=Bearer&amp;Accept=application/xml&amp;searchCriteria=all HTTP/1.1
and get {"message":"\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.","parameters":{"fieldName":"searchCriteria"},

Comment: You are doing something wrong , can you create a video a send to me.